# determine if mysql or percona or mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona

How can i tell if a server I'm connecting to is Percona or MySQL or MariaDB?
Is there any standard way of doing this?
I'm currently using `SHOW VERSION` to test the server version, but I would also need to display the server name in the app I'm working on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that "MySQL" is the original, and the others are spinoffs.  Here is some code that probably always works:

```
version_comment REGEXP 'MariaDB' -- > Mariadb
version_comment REGEXP 'Percona' -- > Percona
else MySQL
```

`version_comment` can be accessed via `SHOW VARIABLES` or `information_schema`.

`@@version` is not reliable because Percona leaves no clue, although I suspect the '-30.3-' is a clue in `5.5.31-30.3-log`.

(I checked 106 servers.)

**Update**

(checking 264 servers.)

```
version         REGEXP 'MariaDB' -- > Mariadb
version_comment REGEXP 'Percona' -- > Percona
else MySQL
```

(And we probably cannot trust for this to be the final word.)

Comment: So I can assume that Percona & MariaDB always report their names and MySQL is acting differently here?

Comment: My answer is based on empirical evidence.  Based on history... MySQL is the base product (now owned by Oracle), so it has no reason to be specific in the settings.  The others are spinoffs, so they feel need for such.

Comment: A longer answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611296/how-can-i-detect-whether-connected-database-is-mariadb-or-mysql/43692813#43692813

Comment: Be warned that this answer is probably outdated. I get version = '10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log', version_commnet = 'Debian 10'. See https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/mdb/system-variables/version_comment/

Comment: @Elvex - Thanks.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can get specific information with:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%vers%'
```

`version` and `version_comment` are very specific.

Comment: on my dev server, `version_comment=(Ubuntu)`, `version=5.5.47-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`. No trace of "MySQL" string anywhere. I've looked trhough all `SHOW VARIABLES` list and nothing relevat came up

Comment: This might be distribution specific then. On Fedora I see "MySQL Community Server (GPL)" or "MariaDB Server" for the two instances I'm testing with.

Comment: Seems so, the example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html states `Source distribution`.

Comment: Does Percona have any special variables you can pick out?

Comment: I don't have access to that server anymore. It was reinstalled. I would expect that the innodb_* variables to be named xtradb_*, but I wouldn't call this a clear answer to my problem.