# How can I detect whether connected database is MariaDB or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, version, mariadb

My PHP application has requirements, including "*either MySQL 5.7+ or MariaDB 10.2+*". How can I tell which of these alternatives is satisfied?

I know how to compare version numbers, and also to get the version number from the database, but I don't know how to determine which kind of database it is.

I tried

```sql
select version()
```

That returns only the version number and server OS information, but not the database kind.

Answer (score 3):

```
$info = $pdo->query("SHOW VARIABLES like '%version%'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$server_vendor  = strtok($info['version_comment']," ");
$server_version = $info['version'];
```

Comment: Actually any of these variables contain database server name, so also your command gives me only info about version and OS.

Comment: In some situations they include "MySQL" or "mariadb.org".  Perhaps all MariaDB cases; I cannot tell.

Answer (score 3):

Look in `VARIABLES` for `aria_block_size`.  Its existence almost certainly implies some version of MariaDB and *not* MySQL, nor Percona.  (At least for the near future.)

The beginning part of `version`:

- "5.7" and "8.0" Imply MySQL or Percona; it will not imply MariaDB.
- "10.2" Implies MariaDB; it is unlikely for MySQL and Percona to get to "10" for a long time.

What feature are you needing?  There is a chance that Percona will retrofit something from MariaDB 10.2 before it comes from MySQL.

Even when `version` is `5.1.53-rel11.7-log` or `5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2-log`, the first part gives you the important part of the MySQL/MariaDB/Percona version.

Percona versions look like:  `5.5.31-30.3-log`, `5.6.30-76.3-56-log`, `5.6.19-67.0-log` -- Note the extra 2 or 3 numbers after the initial 3.

MariaDB always starts with `N.N.N-MariaDB`

Oracle's MySQL starts with `N.N.N`, but might continue with `-enterprise` (paid version), `-community` (free version), `-0ubuntu0` (ported by Ubuntu), `-Debian`, etc.

MariaDB: 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5
Oracle and Percona: 5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0

The 8.0 cycle is just beginning.  This means that 5.6 will soon be closing down and 5.7 has some life left, but not much new will be but in it.

Clarification of what is a "major" release.
For MySQL (and Percona), these are "major", and they are not
consecutive':  5.1, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 8.0.
For MariaDB: 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 10.0, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5.

Comment: Yeah, changing major from 5 to 8 at once means they don't want to catch  up soon.

Comment: I added some more version info.

Comment: Added a list of the "major" releases.  MySQL (and friends) do not consider "5." to be "major".  Instead, 5.7 is major; 5.7.17 is "minor".

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to do this from inside the php app you can (
which php version?) for PHP 7 use mysqli_get_server_info; or  < php 7, use mysql_get_Server_info

```
    <?php
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* print server version */
    printf("Server version: %s\n", mysqli_get_server_info($link));

    /* close connection */
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

will return

Server version: 5.5.5-10.1.23-**MariaDB**-9+deb9u1

php 7 http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php
php 5 & <  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-get-server-info.php